# AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, attributeerror

I have the following script, which uses Tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack

        self.PRINT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Print', fg = 'Red', command = self.Print())
        self.PRINT.pack(side = 'left')    

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Quit', fg = 'Red', command = self.quit())
        self.QUIT.pack(side = 'left')    

    def Print(self):
        print('at least somethings working')

root = tk.Tk()

b = Application(root)    
root.mainloop()
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'tk'

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Unrelated to your question. You are aware that `frame.pack` is _not_ a function call and does not pack anything, aren't you?

Comment: You didn't call `Frame.__init__(self, master)`. Another problem is that your button commands are wrong. Change `command = self.Print()` to `command = self.Print`, otherwise the function is called _immediately_ and the command is set to the return value of the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your script here and got this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 23, in <module>
    b = Application(root)    
  File "t.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.QUIT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Quit', fg = 'Red', command = self.quit())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1283, in quit
    self.tk.quit()
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

The error message appears at the end but the entire stack is important! Let's analyze it.

Apparently, there is an object, instance of an `Application` class, that has no `tk` attribute. Makes sense: we created this class, and we did not add this attribute.

Well, the main loop expects an attribute to exist! What happens is, our class extends `tkinter.Frame`, and a frame need this `tk` attribute. Luckily, we do not have to think how to create it: since all frames need it, the frame initializer (its `__init__()` method) knows how to set this attribute.

What we have to do, then, is just to call the `tkinter.Frame` initializer in our own initializer. This can be easily done by calling the `__init__()` directly from `tk.Frame`, passing the `self` variable:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
```

The entire script will be this, then:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):    

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack

        self.PRINT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Print', fg = 'Red', command = self.Print())
        self.PRINT.pack(side = 'left')    

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(frame, text = 'Quit', fg = 'Red', command = self.quit())
        self.QUIT.pack(side = 'left')    

    def Print(self):
        print('at least somethings working')

root = tk.Tk()

b = Application(root)    
root.mainloop()
```

Now, there will be some other bugs in your script, you'll find soon ;) There is also some complications related to multiple inheritance that can be solved [with the `super()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods). Nonetheless, this is the solution for your first bug.